# C++ includes problems, 6 files, previously defined functions

Tags: c++, file, linker, include

I got 6 files, lets say 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' and 'F', all .cpp. 'A' is the main file, 'B' and 'C' are included in 'A', and 'D', 'E' and 'F' are included in 'B' and in 'C'. In 'D', 'E' and 'F' there is a few classes and namespaces. And a lot of them just throw the 'previously defined' Error. Second day I trying to handle that, reading a lot in Internet, but I'm stuck. The classes I declared and defined in 'D','E' and 'F' are used in 'B' and 'C'.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once

Answer (score 3):

You aren't supposed to include .cpp files.
Put your declarations in .h files and include those.

Comment: and don't forget #pragma once

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion based on the OP?

Comment: He says that he includes .cpp files. Doesn't mention headers.

Comment: @IvanRubinson Ah, yes just spotted it now.

Comment: OK, the problem is that I'm new in c++, I don't know everything and I need to do complicated things, So I missed that Including part. I'm sorry for asking stupid questions. I just didn't find that explained like that. So I decide to ask here. I told here is the place, but I will stop ask here, because its second time I ask and all answers are negative!!!

Comment: O, by the way for those that are not so Pro in the programming. This solution works.